# Monkey Patching class derived from ctypes.Union doesn't work

Tags: python, ctypes, monkeypatching

I am trying to "monkey patch" a class derived from Python ctypes "Union", but I am unable to do so - getting weird errors and sometimes seg-faults. The same thing works quite well when deriving from ctypes "Structure".

I have narrowed this to down to the simplest possible test case which I am posting below. I am using Python 3.6.4. I am wondering if I am doing something wrong (or is there a problem with the ctypes "Union" implementation?). Please see the code below and the corresponding output.

```
import ctypes

def display(self):
  """ A new kind of display """
  return f'Print Type #2: ( {self.y1}, {self.y2} )'

class MyStruct(ctypes.Structure):
  _fields_ = [ 
      ('y1', ctypes.c_uint32),
      ('y2', ctypes.c_uint32)
      ] 

  def __str__(self):
    return f'Print Type #1: [ {self.y1}, {self.y2} ]'

class MyUnion(ctypes.Union):
  _fields_ = [ 
      ('y1', ctypes.c_uint32),
      ('y2', ctypes.c_uint32)
      ] 

  def __str__(self):
    return f'Print Type #1: [ {self.y1}, {self.y2} ]'

if __name__ == '__main__':

  a = MyStruct()
  a.y1 = 10
  a.y2 = 20

  print('Using Structure:')
  print('----------------')
  print(a)
  print('Original :', MyStruct.__str__)
  # monkey patch  __str__ with a different function.
  MyStruct.__str__ = display
  print('Patched :', MyStruct.__str__)
  print('Patched (dict) :', MyStruct.__dict__['__str__'])
  print(a)

  a = MyUnion()
  a.y1 = 10
  a.y2 = 20

  print('Using Union:')
  print('------------')
  print(a)
  print('Original :', MyUnion.__str__)
  # monkey patch  __str__ with a different function.
  MyUnion.__str__ = display
  print('Patched :', MyUnion.__str__)
  print('Patched (dict) :', MyUnion.__dict__['__str__'])
  print(a)
```

Here's the output when I run the program.

```
Using Structure:
----------------
Print Type #1: [ 10, 20 ]
Original : <function MyStruct.__str__ at 0x7fdf89d02e18>
Patched : <function display at 0x7fdf8b0ebe18>
Patched (dict) : <function display at 0x7fdf8b0ebe18>
Print Type #2: ( 10, 20 )
Using Union:
------------
Print Type #1: [ 20, 20 ]
Original : <function MyUnion.__str__ at 0x7fdf89d02f28>
Patched : <function MyUnion.__str__ at 0x7fdf89d02f28>
Patched (dict) : <function display at 0x7fdf8b0ebe18>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ctypes_bug.py", line 54, in <module>
    print(a)
TypeError: 'managedbuffer' object is not callable
```

Clearly, I am able to "patch" `__str__` when the corresponding Python object was derived from "Structure", but I am unable to "patch" `__str__` when the corresponding Python object was derived from "Union".

Interestingly, `MyUnion.__dict__[__str__]` and `MyUnion.__str__` shows different results - which is weird as well.

Is there something I am doing wrong here? I highly appreciate any help or insight!

Comment: Congratulations on being one of those rare people that post a [mcve] the first time!

Answer (score 2):

I think there's an actual CPython bug here. The [`__setattr__` implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.4/Modules/_ctypes/_ctypes.c#L794) for type objects for struct types uses `PyType_Type.tp_setattro`:

```
static int
PyCStructType_setattro(PyObject *self, PyObject *key, PyObject *value)
{
    /* XXX Should we disallow deleting _fields_? */
    if (-1 == PyType_Type.tp_setattro(self, key, value))
        return -1;

    if (value && PyUnicode_Check(key) &&
        _PyUnicode_EqualToASCIIString(key, "_fields_"))
        return PyCStructUnionType_update_stgdict(self, value, 1);
    return 0;
}
```

but [the one for type objects for union types](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.4/Modules/_ctypes/_ctypes.c#L808) uses `PyObject_GenericSetAttr`:

```
static int
UnionType_setattro(PyObject *self, PyObject *key, PyObject *value)
{
    /* XXX Should we disallow deleting _fields_? */
    if (-1 == PyObject_GenericSetAttr(self, key, value))
        return -1;

    if (PyUnicode_Check(key) &&
        _PyUnicode_EqualToASCIIString(key, "_fields_"))
        return PyCStructUnionType_update_stgdict(self, value, 0);
    return 0;
}
```

The use of `PyType_Type.tp_setattro` is necessary to update type slots and invalidate the [internal type attribute cache](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.4/Objects/typeobject.c#L10). `PyObject_GenericSetAttr` doesn't know it should do either of those things, causing potential memory corruption due to "zombie" cached attributes. It looks like the same bug was [fixed](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/08ccf202e606a066668f4ef85df9a9c0d07e1ba1#diff-998bfefaefe2ab83d5f523e18f158fa4) in early 2008 for structs, but they forgot to handle unions.

Comment: I was just opening the answer editor to state the same thing. UnionType is a metaclass, so it should use `PyType_Type.tp_setattro`.

Comment: Also, better link for the changeset: https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/08ccf202e606a066668f4ef85df9a9c0d07e1ba1#diff-998bfefaefe2ab83d5f523e18f158fa4

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Ah, that is better. I didn't find that one, following the git blame.

Comment: Thanks for solving the mystery. I am wondering if there is an easy way to workaround this? I am using a org-wide Python installation and cannot use a locally compiled CPython for this. The ctypes I am using are auto-generated using types.new_class.

Comment: @user2357112: the merge told me it was probably on a release branch by now, and since 2.6 was trunk at the time I indeed found it there.

Comment: @Vijay: there may be a way to use `PyType_Type.tp_setattro` directly via ctypes

Comment: @MartijnPieters Found an even simpler workaround. I can simply wrap the Union inside a Structure and make it anonymous. This seem to resolve the issue in my use case.

Comment: @user2357112: ugh, yes, c&p fail.